# Java (Concurrent)HashMap Performance for Frequent Modifications

Tags: java, dictionary

I use a ConcurrentHashMap (key: String, value: custom object) as one of my data structures. the map contains about 300,000 objects and will be updated frequently (about 20,000 put and 20,000 removes per minute).

It seems, that the whole program slow down after about 1 hour. Can somebody tell me if the ConcurrentHashMap is made for frequent modifications or if there is an alternative which is better for my requirements?

Thanks :)

Comment: 20,000 operations on the map per minute should be ok. Have you tried to profile your program to see where it spends time after an hour? Could it be a memory issue (do you make sure you don't keep a reference to the objects you remove)?

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment. Yes I already profiled the program and there is no memory overflow. If 40,000 operations are ok, then I will search for other problems.

Comment: Do you use any concurrencyLevel in the constructor?

Comment: No I do not. Normally the map is only used by one thread. Some other threads will use it regularly every 30 sec.

Comment: I just ran a quick test: adding and removing 200,000 items from a map containing 300,000 takes about 0.5 seconds (a bit less with 1 thread, a bit more with 20 threads). This will obviously vary + you are probably doing other things in your program but it gives an idea of the magnitude.

Comment: Here is a nice explanation for your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378310/performance-concurrenthashmap-vs-hashmap

Comment: This is more better explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1573901/concurrenthashmap-constructor-parameters

Comment: Have you checked how many hash collisions you have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used `ConcurrentHashMap` in production with many writers/readers @ > 100,000 read/writes per minute. We'd let the system run for days but I never encountered any slowdown due to `ConcurrentHashMap`.

If your code is slowing down after an hour, the first thing I'd suspect is GC overhead due to a memory leak. If I were you I'd hookup jvisualvm to your app. and monitor the memory/CPU usage and go from there.

Comment: So the JVM option -XX:-UseParallelOldGC and -XX:+UseGCOverheadLimit may be helpful.

Comment: @RomanC: IMO if your app is noticeably slowing down due to GC overhead, either (1) there is a memory leak that needs to be fixed, or (2) the heap is too small for the app. I wouldn't recommend fiddling with GC implementation. UseGCOverheadLimit should be enabled by default, and merely helps detecting memory problems earlier.